# jsrender issue with layout templates

Tags: jsrender

I downloaded the latest version of [jsRender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender) and I saw that the layout templates doesn't "supported". I used to use

```
{{for ListData  tmpl="#LayoutTmpl" ~variable=value Layout=true  /}}
```

but after a quick view in jsRender js code I saw that in the latest version the "Layout" variable renamed to "isLayout". I tried this

```
 {{for ListData  tmpl="#LayoutTmpl" ~variable=value isLayout=true  /}}


<script id="LayoutTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
 {{:#parent.parent.data.propertyName}}
   {{if #data.length > 0}}
     {{for #data}}
       {{:propertyName}}
     {{/for}}
   {{else}}
       do something
   {{/if}}
</script>
```

but with no luck. The nested layout template is rendered as a normal template and since the data object isn't recognized as a type of list, I am getting the "do something".

Does anyone know how could I fix this? of course I want to avoid rollback to the previous version.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a sample showing how to achieve that scenario, in the new design here: [headers and footers sample](http://borismoore.github.com/jsrender/demos/scenarios/05_arrays-plus-headers-and-footers.html).

Also, see the reply to your issue on GitHub [here](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender/issues/124)